# can not load keys : scan commands not supported by redis server

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I am working on the `windows version of Redis server`. Version is `redis-2.4.5-win32-win64`.

I have started redis server:

> [4748] 14 Jul 19:12:32 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'
>   [4748] 14 Jul 19:12:32 * Server started, Redis version 2.4.5

When I am trying to connect to the Redis server, I am getting the below error.

[image]

**Redis Desktop version is : 0.9.3.817**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the document of Redis, the command SCAN is available since 2.8.0. However your Redis version is older than this one, so you couldn't use SCAN command in your env.

FYR: [Redis Scan Command Documentation](https://redis.io/commands/scan)

Comment: Could you please let me me from where can I download redis latest version ?

Comment: @Prateek Windows ports lags very far behind. Take a look at this one https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases

Comment: @ Imaskar - Thanks. You're right. Need to switch to ubuntu now :)